# How do I populate an array with values sourced from WorksheetFunction.Unique()?

Tags: excel, vba, unique, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get an array of unique values sourced from a `ListObject` table. I'm trying to use the 'Unique' method of the `WorksheetFunction` object, but I'm getting a host of errors however I try to write the code.
How do I use `WorksheetFunction.Unique` to populate an array?

Here's a pseudocode skeleton:

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim Rng As Range
Dim UniqueArr() As String

Set Rng = Ws.ListObjects("Table").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange

Set UniqueArr() = WorksheetFunction.Unique(Rng) '--Fill UniqueArr() with these values
```

I can't set the size of the array without knowing how many unique values there are, but I can't fetch the unique values to count them.

**EDIT**:

I've removed the `set` part, and changed to `variant` and now it works, but I have a second question.

Why is UniqueArr() now 2 dimensional? To fetch a value from it I need to use UniqueArr(1,1), not UniqueArr(1).

Comment: Without `Set`  arrays are no objects. And if that does not work `Dim UniqueArr() As Variant` aswell.

Comment: 1) Do NOT use `Set` on your array.  2) yes, as @Pᴇʜ says, you cannot assign Excel output to a string array, it has to be an array of Variant. And 3) tell us what the actual error is.

Comment: Because every range is 2 dimensional even if it has only one row or one column. Why is that? Because otherwise you cannot say if it is a column or a row. `UniqueArr(5)` can be 5 values in a row or in a column `UniqueArr(1, 5)` is 1 row 5 columns and `UniqueArr(5, 1)` is 5 rows 1 column. So that is why arrays retrieved from ranges are always 2 dimensional.

Comment: What @Pᴇʜ says.  Be forewarned however,  Excel has a nasty habit of converting single-cell ranges into single value Variants (that is, ***not*** arrays) when it returns them to VBA.  So if the returned array would have only one cell (i.e., A(1 to 1, 1 to 1)) most excel functions will return a single-valued Variant instead.

Comment: Actually if you declare an array with parenthesis like `Dim UniqueArr() As Variant`. So it errors if any Excel function returns a `Variant` value. If you declare it as `Dim UniqueArr As Variant` then `UniqueArr` can be an array or a value. So you can check it with `IsArray(UniqueArr)` and `ReDim UniqueArr(1 To 1, 1 To 1) As Variant` and put in the value you got. This way your code can handle it like an array even if it is a single value.